# TypeScript: Initialize interface like array (without specifying member name)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an interface:

```
interface Rect {
        width: number
        height: number
    }
```

I can initialize it like that:

```
const SomeRect : Rect = {
        width: 5,
        height: 10
    };
```

But, can I initialize it like an array?

```
const SomeRect : Rect = [5, 10];
```

It may be useful if I will try to initialize an array of interfaces, for example:

```
const SomeRects : Array<Rect> = [
        [5, 10],
        [15, 20],
        [30, 50]
    ];
```

P.S.: I don't want to use an array, because I couldn't get members (width and height) by name, but only by index.

Comment: You're asking if you can use the array literal syntax to initialize an object which is not an array? If so the answer is no. You can write a factory `function rect([length, width]:  [number, number]): Rect { return {length, width}; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of what you want can be achieved with a [Tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple).

You can define a `Rect` as an array of length 2 where both elements are of type `number`.

```
type Rect = [number, number]
```

Your `SomeRect` and `SomeRects` examples are both valid with this definition.

```
const SomeRect: Rect = [5, 10];

const SomeRects: Array<Rect> = [
  [5, 10],
  [15, 20],
  [30, 50]
];
```

> P.S.: I don't want to use an array, because I couldn't get members (width and height) by name, but only by index.

In order to support accessing by name, you would need to convert to an object or use a helper function.

Helpers using destructuring instead of numeric indexes:

```
const rectWidth = ([width]: Rect) => width;

const rectHeight = ([_, height]: Rect) => height;
```

Conversion (similar to @Aluan Haddad's comment):

```
interface KeyedRect {
  width: number
  height: number
}

const toKeyedRect = ([width, height]: Rect) => ({
  width,
  height
})
```